# How to preserve extra modules if publishing from source?

Tags: orchardcms

Im getting up to speed with Orchard.  So far I like what I see.  So ive downloaded the source and am about to try using this as utility site for one of our teams.  There will likely be some source code changes but how can I preserve the use of some of the extra modules being referenced from the gallery?  Will I have to re-install/reconfigure these modules each time?  Or do I need to include those modules in the solution for building each time?

Comment: I have never deployed Orchard with third party modules so I'm making a lot of assumptions here but I think if you install them from the gallery they get added to the Modules folder under Orchard.Web just the same as if you downloaded them and moved them there manually. So when you publish, they should still be included. If you copy your database from your development environment to production everything should remain enabled. Otherwise, if you're starting with a clean slate you'll have to make sure that all the modules and features you need are enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my approach:

You should add the modules to the solution and add project dependencies to e.g. Orchard.Core. This way the modules get published together with the Orchard stuff.

To make life easier, also put the whole solution under version control to see what has changed when you need to update later on.